# how to change icon dropdown in splitButton primeng 17

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, primeng

I want to change the `splitButton` dropdown icon in primeng version 17

I looked in the documentation of the `splitButton` part, there is a feature called icon, I changed it, but the label part changed, I want to change this part that I show in the photo.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a stackblitz for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the dropdown icon, you should use the `dropdownicon` template

Example

```
<p-splitButton
    label="Save"
    icon="pi pi-plus"
    (onClick)="save('info')"
    [model]="items"
  >
    <ng-template pTemplate="dropdownicon">
      <i class="pi pi-arrow-circle-down"></i>
    </ng-template>
</p-splitButton>
```

[Demo on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/e4ccub?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdemo%2Fsplit-button-basic-demo.html)

For more details: please check: [Dropdownicon templates](https://primeng.org/splitbutton#api.splitbutton.templates.dropdownicon)